# How to print reports in batch by passing multiple values

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a list of students, I want to print a Fee slip for each student I am using a SQL storedProcedure to get the data and Crystal Reports. The thing I want to do is, open all `ReportViewer` pass all the `studentIds` and show them in preview section.

I did:

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rd.Load(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\CognitiveDev\TKS Management System\Reports\FeeSlip.rpt");

    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Other"].ConnectionString;
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("PrintFeeSlip", conn);
        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (int gotId in gotList)
        {
           sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmissionNumber", gotId);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds, "FeeSlip");
            rd.SetDataSource(ds);

            reportView.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rd;
            reportView.ViewerCore.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
    }
}
```

This code works for single but what should I do for multiple `stdID`

[image]

Comment: You would need a different report. The one you have currently is designed to show data for a single student. You need a report that can show the data for multiple students.

Comment: how can I do this? Please guide me.

Comment: Guide you how? You need a different report. It could accept a table valued parameter for the student id values. There just isn't concrete here to offer any help.